# How to implement Android Volley with OkHttp 2.0?

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

This OkHttpStack is no longer supported in OkHttp2.0:
https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899

What is the current pattern to integrate OkHttp 2.0.0 with Volley?

Comment: There is a comment already on that gist pointing to [an OkHttp 2.0 version of `HttpStack` support](https://gist.github.com/ceram1/8254f7a68d81172c1669).

Comment: Yes, but the class that ceram1 posted has a customized cache handling. I was looking for the simplest way. And also, I have no idea if that implementation is optimal/standard/correct

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You must use okhttp-urlconnection module that implements the java.net.HttpURLConnection API, so:

- Download or set a dependency for [okhttp-urlconnection](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp-urlconnection/2.0.0/okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar)
- Rewrite your OkHttpStack to make use of the OkUrlFactory class:

  ```
  public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
     private final OkUrlFactory okUrlFactory;
     public OkHttpStack() {
         this(new OkUrlFactory(new OkHttpClient())); 
     }
     public OkHttpStack(OkUrlFactory okUrlFactory) {
         if (okUrlFactory == null) {
             throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
         }
         this.okUrlFactory = okUrlFactory;
     }
     @Override
     protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
         return okUrlFactory.open(url);
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: I used this solution and added the following gradle dependencies: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1'`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this also

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory;

/**
 * An {@link com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack HttpStack} implementation
 * which uses OkHttp as its transport.
 */
public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
    private final OkUrlFactory mFactory;

    public OkHttpStack() {
        this(new OkHttpClient());
    }

    public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client) {
        if (client == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
        }
        mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more readable than the @fjmontiel answer but besides that is exactly the same, isn't it?

Comment: yes!, there are many gist available depending upon the requirement like for ssl https://gist.github.com/tbruyelle/0729aef4df2c11b21fdf

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this now without the dependency on HttpURLConnection:

https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/31jhDwaCvtg

https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750