# Improving the latency of server response under high-volme traffic

Tags: php, android, mysql, high-availability, high-load

I have an e-commerce application and it works perfectly when 5 to 10 users are using it.

But it becomes really slow when it is used by 50-60 people.

Currently I am using MySQL & PHP.

I am calling `.php` file which has `MySQL` connectivity code. And from there I am fetching JSON response.

Below is my code:

```
    class Items extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Itemid));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_allitems, "GET",
                    params);



            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);


                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ITEMID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_master") ;

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["items"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $item = array();
        $item["id"] = $row["id"];
        $item["code"] = $row["code"];
        $item["name"] = $row["name"];
        $item["description"] = $row["description"];
        $item["price"] = $row["price"];
        $item["image1"] = $row["image1"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["items"], $product);

    }
    // success
    $response["psuccess"] = 1;
   ....
}
```

So what are the best approaches for optimization in this scenario ? When more than 1000 users will access this app, the app should be responsive and load items quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, you need to look into techniques for managing a large number of connections, such as [enabling servers to handle high-volume traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24675/3287204), as well as network-level issues like [dynamic load balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/337634/separating-dynamic-and-static-content-on-high-traffic-website).

On the client side, you can make use of [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) with [`okHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). You'd also have to enable the usage of [`okHttp` on the server side](http://readwrite.com/2012/04/20/using-spdy-on-your-web-server) for that to work properly.

**References:**

**1.** [Tactics for using PHP in a high-load site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24675/3287204).

**2.** [Separating dynamic and static content on high traffic website](https://serverfault.com/questions/337634/separating-dynamic-and-static-content-on-high-traffic-website).

**3.** [How to implement Android Volley with OkHttp 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24375043/3287204)

**4.** [Using SPDY on Your Web Server](http://readwrite.com/2012/04/20/using-spdy-on-your-web-server).